# Long crank but still starts

Tags: starting, jeep, water, compass

I am in need of some help. I have an 08 Jeep Compass Sport. 2.4 4x4. We have been having a lot of rain and a lot of flooding. I was on my way home from work, and I came to an area where the road was flooded. Now I wanted to turn around but the cars behind me wouldn't move so I had no choice but to slowly drive through. The water was up to my bumper.

About a month before this, my check engine light came on. My secondary fan was malfunctioning. So I had a mechanic check out why it wasn't working. The wire for this fan going to the relay was broken off from corrosion. When he was done with the car he went to pull it out but it wouldn't start. Here the starter wire is also corroded. He fixed it.

Here is the part where the flooded road come into play. Ever since I drove through the water, my jeep has a long crank when the engine is warm. It will crank for about 3 to 5 seconds before starting. When the engine is cool, it starts right up.

Could it be that water got into the relay? The starter wire? My boyfriend seems to think the coil packs need changing. I have new spark plugs, mass airflow sensor and throttle body. It's not throwing any codes. I'm at a loss right now. Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say, "my jeep has a long crank when it's **warm**" ... is that when the vehicle is warm or when it's warm outside? As well, when "it" isn't warm, does it start right up? I don't think your coil packs need changed, because those are usually all or nothing ... either they work or they don't. And, coil packs don't usually go out as a group, but singly. Do you know if you did a throttle relearn when the throttle body was replaced?

Comment: Its when the jeep is warm. I could drive down the road about a block or 2, shut it off and restart it and it has a long crank. Throttle body was replaced last year and yes we relearned it. – Jeepgirl 2 hours ago Delete

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but to make sure I'm clear on what you're saying, when the Jeep is completely cool, it starts right up ... is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Sorry im new to this.

Comment: It’s entirely possible that it could be the relay box or the pcm. Both are located in the left front wheel well iirc. Without testing it would be hard to say. You could try pulling the fender liner and inspecting the pcm connector and relay box for water intrusion.

Comment: Ok. Will do that this weekend. How would one test it?

Comment: @Jeepgirl I edited your question to add the info from the comments here.  If you have more details, you can feel free to edit your question to clarify too -- just click the edit button at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Now if there is water intrusion, would it dry out on its own? Today is the first day it hasnt rained and its 80 outside. Its been in the 60s and rained everyday since driving thru the water.

Comment: @Ben - Why would that affect it only when the vehicle is warmed up (or even partially), though?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the main power relay is in that box. It’s a retarded design. It could be that corrosion formed and the relay heating up is pushing resistance too high causing voltage drop.

Comment: @Jeepgirl you need to pull the wheel and fender liner off in the left front. If you pull the lower cover off the relay box you’re looking for corrosion. The pcm has weather pack seals but it won’t stop water from wicking up the wires sometimes. You’d need to pull each connector off again looking for corrosion or wetness.

Comment: I have a relay that I pulled off a 07 compass so we could fix the wire for the fan. There is no corrosion on it. If there is on mine maybe we should just swap out the whole relay box?

Comment: @Ben - I can see that, but wouldn't that provide continual resistance and prevent starting at all? Why would it *just* increase cranking time before start?

Comment: I would check the intake air temp sensor and the block temp sensor. If it's a cold engine block the PCM won't know to enrichen (choke) the mix and will make it hard to start. A warm engine block will start up.

Answer (score 0):

Before I would change coil packs and the like I would check to see if any of the temperature sensors on the block or air intake might have been damaged by the water. Water not only gets into the connections, it pushes wires and connectors around and if you had corroded broken wires on there before, the water may have knocked off or shorted a temperature sensor. Get a flashlight and go over the whole engine, top and bottom, looking for any more broken or corroded wire ends.